# Expected number of coin flip to get HTT by conditioning

Tags: random-variables, markov-chains, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

What is the expected number of (fair) coin flips to get a sequence HTT? I know similar questions have been asked before and that the answer should be $8$, but I can't seem to get my head around this one. I'd like to solve it using conditional expectation technique (rather than Markov chains).

So let $X$ be the random variable "number of flips needed to get the sequence HTT". I condition on first 3 flips. Then the set of 4 events $\{HTT, T, HTH, HH\}$ partitions the sample space. We have

$E(X) = E(X|HTT)P(HTT) + E(X|T)P(T) + E(X|HTH)P(HTH) + E(X|HH)P(HH),$

Now $E(X|HTT) = 3$,  $\quad E(X|T) = 1+E(X).$

Corresponding probabilities are $P(HTT) = \frac{1}{8}$, $\quad P(T) = \frac{1}{2}$, $\quad P(HTH) = \frac{1}{8}$, $\quad P(HH) = \frac{1}{4}$.

What I don't know is how to compute $E(X|HTH)$ and $E(X|HH)$. Please help.

Comment: I think that, once you clarify things, you'll still be talking about states.  You have the starting state, you have the state where the last toss with $H$ and the state in which the last two tosses were $HT$.  If you want, you can use conditional probability from those states.

Comment: I clarified my original statement @lulu

Comment: So you are saying that I still need to use some ideas from Markov chain theory? @lulu

Comment: Well, I'm saying that those ideas clarify everything.  For instance, the states $HTH$ and $HH$ are the same...all that matters is that the last toss with $H$, the earlier part of the string is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

**Conditional Approach**

$T$ represents a $T$ before the first $H$; all other $T$s are covered below.
The other cases are $H$, $TH$, $TT$

**Equations**

Tossing an initial $T$ just adds one to the expected duration
$$
E[X|T]=1+E[X]\tag1
$$
Tossing an $H$ adds $1$ and then $H$, $TH$, or $TT$
$$
E[X|H]=1+\frac12E[X|H]+\frac14E[X|TH]+\frac14E[X|TT]\tag2
$$
Tossing a $TH$ adds $2$ and then $H$, $TH$, or $TT$
$$
E[X|TH]=2+\frac12E[X|H]+\frac14E[X|TH]+\frac14E[X|TT]\tag3
$$
Tossing $TT$ after the first $H$ adds $2$ and ends
$$
E[X|TT]=2\tag4
$$
The expected duration is
$$
E[X]=\frac12E[X|T]+\frac12E[X|H]\tag5
$$
**Solution**

Equations $(1)$ and $(5)$ give
$$
E[X]=1+E[X|H]\tag6
$$
Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ give
$$
E[X|TH]=1+E[X|H]\tag7
$$
Plugging $(4)$ and $(7)$ into $(2)$ gives
$$
E[X|H]=7\tag8
$$
Finally, $(6)$ and $(8)$ yield
$$
E[X]=8\tag9
$$

---

**Generating Function Approach**

The possible string of $H$s and $T$s can start with any number of $T$s, whose generating function is
$$
1+\frac x2+\frac{x^2}4+\frac{x^3}8+\cdots=\frac1{1-\frac x2}\tag{10}
$$
Note that the exponent of $x$ represents the number of tosses, while the coefficient represents the probability.

After the initial string of $T$s, atoms of $H$ and $HT$ can follow, whose generating function is
$$
1+\overbrace{\left(\frac x2+\frac{x^2}4\right)^{\vphantom{2}}}^\text{$1$ atom}+\overbrace{\left(\frac x2+\frac{x^2}4\right)^2}^\text{$2$ atoms}+\cdots=\frac1{1-\frac x2-\frac{x^2}4}\tag{11}
$$
Finally, the string must end with $HTT$ whose generating function is
$$
\frac{x^3}8\tag{12}
$$
Thus, the full generating function is
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\overbrace{\ \frac{1\vphantom{x^3}}{1-\frac x2}\ }^{\substack{\text{any number}\\\text{of $T$s}}}\overbrace{\frac{1\vphantom{x^3}}{1-\frac x2-\frac{x^2}4}}^{\substack{\text{any number}\\\text{of $H$ and $HT$s}}}\overbrace{\quad\frac{x^3}8\quad}^{\substack{\text{terminal}\vphantom{\text{y}}\\\text{$HTT$}}}\tag{13}\\
&=\frac{x^3}{x^3-8x+8}\tag{14}\\[6pt]
%&=\frac{x^3}8+\frac{x^4}8+\frac{x^5}8+\frac{7x^6}{64}+\frac{3x^7}{32}+\frac{5x^8}{64}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is the probability that we get $HTT$ after exactly $n$ tosses. Thus, since
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty p_kx^k\tag{15}\\
&=\frac{x^3}{x^3-8x+8}\tag{16}
\end{align}
$$
the total probability of all possibilities is $f(1)=1$.

Furthermore, since
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty kp_kx^{k-1}\tag{17}\\
&=\frac{8x^2(3-2x)}{\left(x^3-8x+8\right)^2}\tag{18}
\end{align}
$$
the expected duration is $f'(1)=8$.

Comment: I don't understand how you get expressions (2) and (3) ? @robjohn

Comment: So for (2) you say when you initially toss H, this adds 1 and then either then H, TH or TT... Why? In my mind, tossing H initially surely decreases expected duration since you "only" need to flip TT next... @robjohn

Comment: $(2)$: tossing $H$ adds $1$ to the count because of the $H$. After  that toss, there is a $\frac12$ chance to toss another $H$ a $\frac14$ chance to toss a $TH$ and  a $\frac14$ chance to toss a $TT$. $(3)$: Tossing $TH$ adds $2$ to the count because of the $TH$ and then we have the same options, with the same chances after.

Comment: In other words, for (2) are you computing $E(X|H)$ by conditioning yet again? If so, why don't you just consider the potential outcomes of the next flip, i.e. why don't you use $E(X|H) = E(X|H|H)P(H) + E(X|H|T)P(T)$ ? Why bother to consider $TH$ and $TT$ at that stage, instead of simply $T$ and $H$?

Comment: $T$ counts differently before and after the first $H$. This seemed the easiest way to handle things.

Comment: It occurs to me that, perhaps, part of the confusion is the use of $E[X|Y]$ in the first section. $E[X|Y]$ represents the expected number of tosses to obtain $HTT$, including $Y$. The possible sequences can start with $0$ or more $T$s before the first $H$. After the first $H$, $0$ or more atoms from $\{H,TH\}$, and a terminal $TT$. That $TH$ and $TT$ are only considered after the first $H$ tossed is because they are only included in $E[X|H]$ and subsequently in $E[X|TH]$. Thus, we can uniquely break down any allowable sequence into the cases given.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give a solution using martingale theory (note I learned this myself about 5min ago so I could be very wrong), which is a bit excessive but gives you a generalized solution to find the expected number of tosses needed to see any pattern of any length, and can be adapted to solve similar problems.

Consider a gambling game where you have a sequence of gamblers such that, g<sub>i</sub>, each starting with 1, and every round they bet all that they have. If they win, they gain $ \frac{1}{P(win)}*k $ where $ k $ is the amount bet. Hence, the game is fair (expected gain is 0). Let $X_n$ be the result of the $n^{th}$ flip. The way the game work is that, $g_i$ bets on round i that $X_i = H$. If they win, they bet on $X_{i+1} = T$ the next round. If they win again, they bet on $X_{i+2} = T$.

Let $M_n$ be the gain of the casino after n rounds. Since the game is fair, $M_n$ is a mean 0 martingale w.r.t. the filtration generated by $X_n$. Let $t$ be the round where we first see HTT, after which the game ends. Since $P(t > 3) <= 1-2^3$ and more generally, $P(t > 3n) <= (1-2^3)^n$, we see that we are $E(t) = \sum_{n>=0}P(t>= n) < \infty$ and $E(|M_{n+1}-M_{n}||F_n) <= 3*2^3$ since at most 3 people are betting each round, we see can apply Doob's Optional Stopping Theorem and conclude that $E(M_t) = 0$.
We see that every gambler before $g_{t-2}$ is out, $g_{t-2}$ won $2^3 = 8$, $g_{t-1}$ and $g_t$ both lost in the first round, so $E(M_t) = E(t) - 8$, which gives $E(t) = 8$.

This may seem needlessly complicated, but depending on your circumstances, you can hand-wave the OST part. And you can apply this to other problems, like using this method, it is easy to see that the expected number of tosses to see HTH is 10, HHH is 14, HTHTHT is $2^6 + 2^4+2^2$, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of flips to get $HTT$.

The goal is to compute $E(X)$.

For each sequence $Y\in\{H,HT\}$, let $X|Y$ be the number of flips to get $HTT$ assuming an initial sequence $Y$ where the sequence $Y$ is allowed to potentially be used to form $HTT$ but where the flip count starts at $0$ after the initial sequence $Y$ (i.e., the length of $Y$ doesn't count toward the flip count).

Then we get the equations
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
E(X)&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigl(1+E(X|H)\bigr)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigl(1+E(X)\bigr)\\[4pt]
E(X|H)&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigl(1+E(X|H)\bigr)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigl(1+E(X|HT)\bigr)\\[4pt]
E(X|HT)&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigl(1+E(X|H)\bigr)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
which is a system of $3$ linear equations in the $3$ unknowns $E(X),E(X|H),E(X|HT)$.

Solving the system yields $E(X)=8$.

Comment: quasi, could you please explain how (first) equation for $E(X)$ is derived?

Comment: $E(X)$ is the expected number of flips to get $HTT$ assuming no relevant prior sequence.

Comment: For the case where the next flip is $H$, the expected number of flips to get $HTT$ is the probability of getting a flip of $H$ times $\bigl(1+E(X|H)\bigr)$, where the summand of $1$ accounts for the one flip just used, and the summand $E(X|H)$ represents the expected number of remaining flips to get $HTT$ assuming a prior sequence of $H$.

Comment: Similarly, for the case where the next flip is $T$, the expected number of flips to get $HTT$ is the probability of getting a flip of $T$ times $\bigl(1+E(X)\bigr)$, where the summand of $1$ accounts for the one flip just used, and the summand $E(X)$ reflects the fact that an initial flip of $T$ is not a useful initial sequence, so can be ignored. In other words, the case of an initial $T$ adds $1$ to the flip count but then just resets the state to the initial state.

Comment: I’m sorry but I still don’t get your expression for $E(X)$. According to conditional expectation formula, we should have $E(X) = E(X|H)P(H) + E(X|T)P(T)$, so why does the extra $1$ appearin your first term, e.g.  $(1+E(X|H))$? It should surely be just $E(X|H)$... Note that I understand why you have $1$ in your second term - it comes because if you got $T$, you have wasted a flip, it’s just the first term which bothers me. And I have the same problem with your next conditional equation for $E(X|H)$. To me it seems you are adding $1$ in places where they should not be.

Comment: I'm using the notation $E(X|Y)$ to mean the expected number of _additional_ steps _after_ the sequence $Y$, so with that definition, you need to add $1$ to account for the flip that got you to that state.

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the answers on this thread and on 521130 as reference, I will answer the question in a way which was easier to follow for me, using "recursion" and just the definition of the law of total probability.

Let $X$ denote the event where we observe $HTT$ in sequence. Let $HH$ or any other permutation of $H$ and $T$ denote the event of observing them in succession.

\begin{align}
E[X] &= 0.5E(1+E[X|H]) + 0.5E(1+E[X]) \tag{1} \\
     &= 2 + E[X|H] \tag{2}
\end{align}
Where we get $(1)$ since if we observe $T$ then the sequence has to start from the beginning.

Using the law of total probability, we can iterate until we reach the sequence.

\begin{align}
E[X|H] &= 1 + 0.5E[X|HT] + 0.5E[X|H] \tag{3}\\
       &= 2 + E[X|HT] \tag{4}
\end{align}

Where in $(3)$ the key idea is that if we get another $H$ then the expected number of flips remaining is unchanged.

\begin{align}
E[X|HT] &= 1 + 0.5\underbrace{E[X|HTT]}_0 + 0.5E[X|H] \tag{5}
\end{align}

Now you can simply plug the value of $E[X|HT]$ into $(4)$ and "iterate out of the stack."